# column size of varchar in hive orc

Tags: hive, orc

I have a problem with orc format in hive.
I create 2 tables with different format, default text and orc. as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_varchar_1`(
  `name` varchar(1)
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
;

CREATE TABLE `test_varchar_2`(
  `name` varchar(1)
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
;
```

then, insert to table:

```
insert into test_varchar_1
select 'hello' as name union all
select '你好' as name --two Chinese characters,means 'hello'
;

insert into test_varchar_2
select 'hello' as name union all
select '你好' as name --two Chinese characters,means 'hello'
;
```

then , select tables:

```
hive> select name from test_varchar_1;
OK
h
你

hive> select name from test_varchar_2;
OK
h
�
```

In test_varchar_1, the result is one letter and one character, looks right. but test_varchar_2(use orc) , couldn't fetch character.
it looks like some utf8 encoding problem, or something else?

BTW, when i create table use varchar(3) in orc format, i can fetch 3 letters and 1 characters.

```
# test_varchar_3 use orc format and `name` is varchar(3)
hive> select name from test_varchar_3;
OK
hel
你
```

I want to change orc varchar like default text ,means 1 varchar size can fetch 1 letter or 1 character.how can i change it.
thanks!

Comment: why do you want to use `varchar` datatype with ORC format and not string ?

Comment: @GaurangShah  I use sqoop to import from mysql, which datatype is varchar. sqoop auto create hive table , for example , use hive varchar(50) to match mysql varchar(50). so here is my problem. cant't fetch 50 characters in hive table  with orc.

Comment: use `--map-column-java column_name=column_type` to map your column to string datatype.

Comment: @GaurangShah it works.but so many tables and so many varchar field. I want a simple way.